# How to make my VirtualBox VM's icon nicer than the red forbidden icon?

Tags: virtualbox, dock, 19.04

Here is how my VM looks like in the dock when running in Ubuntu 19.04:

[image: VirtualBox VM red icon]

How can I change it to a nicer icon, at least something that does not look like a fatal error?

Comment: Lock session, Unlock session. And icon is good...